# How to echo a php array for dynamic javascript

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I am using Google Analytics API to pull Total Visits and put into Googles Javascript to display in a bar graph.  I am having issues trying to put an array to the variables.  When I do a `print_r` it spits out everything just fine but I need it to spit out everything just as it is.  This is what I got so far:

```
//I connect to my own SQL database for $num

//Connect to Google Analytics
$mystart = '2012-02-28';

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

        $ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('source'),array('visits', 'visitBounceRate'),'-visits', $filter, $mystart, $mystart);

//adds +1 day to date 
$mystart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($mystart)));

$totalvisits = $ga->getVisits();

//These are my arrays  
$adddate[] = "data.addColumn('number', '" . $mystart . "');";
$addvisits[] = "$totalvisits,";
        }
```

This is what I am trying to achieve through the use of echos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        // This is where I want to put something like <? echo $adddate ?> but of course doesn't work
        data.addColumn('number', '2012-02-28');
        data.addColumn('number', '2012-02-29');
        data.addColumn('number', '2012-03-01');
        data.addColumn('number', '2012-03-02');
        data.addColumn('number', '2012-03-03');
        data.addRows([
        // This is where I want to put something like <? echo $addvisits ?> but of course doesn't work
          ['Feb. 28 to March 3', 100, 105, 91, 80, 150]
        ]);
</script>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using [`JSON`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking how to output the array in the way you want, then use something like:

```
echo implode("\r\n", $adddate);
```

See [`implode`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/implode).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  The `implode` is key of course, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making an array, and then echoing it as JSON, and having JS loop over it.

For example:

```
$adddate[] = array('type' => 'number', 'value' => $mystart);
```

And then:

```
var addDate = <?php echo json_encode($adddate); ?>;
for(var i = 0, len = addDate.length; i < len; i++){
   var val = addDate[i];
   data.addColumn(val.number, val.value);
}
```

Then you can do something similar for `$addvisits`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it will work, you cannot echo an array. The easiest way is to implode them

Use these codes, where you are echoing them right now

```
echo implode("",$adddate);
echo implode("",$addvisits);
// User \r\n to implode if you need to add linebreaks
```

Answer (score -2):

Why is it an array, when there is only one value? use simply this:

```
$adddate = "data.addColumn('number', '" . $mystart . "');";
```

(remove the [])

and then the `<? echo $adddate ?>` will work

Comment: What if he wanted to add more values?  Note `$adddate[]` is in a `while` loop.